# Git gvim diff can't show difference

Tags: git, vim

I would like to use gVim(7.3) for the git diffs. I use cygwin and this is my .gitconfig-File.

```
[diff]
    tool = my_gvimdiff
[difftool "my_gvimdiff"]
    cmd = gvim -d "$(cygpath -w $LOCAL)" "$REMOTE"
[alias]
    dt = difftool
```

My problem is, that gVim is inovked with the correct files in diffmode, but I don't see any colorized diffs. gVim gives me E97 and says it can't create the difference during startup. The curios thing is, if I start editing the local file, e.g. I add a new line, then I see only this difference(colorized) to the commited file.
What's wrong with my configuration? Can anybody give me a hint...

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're on windows. I'm also guessing you might have Cygwin/MSYSGIT mixtures.

In such case, the environment is not the same depending on how you launched Vim

- from GIT Bash
- from cygwin bash
- from cmd.exe
- launched from TortoiseGit, Visual Studio or another application or service

Vim is likely not finding an external `diff` command (or is finding some kind of Windows/DOS command by that name which is not adequate).

Comment: I launched gVim for the cygwin bash. As note, I have the cygwin git package installed.